# Saving a file at the Jar location

Tags: java, command-line, jar, path

I want to save a file at a folder that is in the same location as the application jar file. I am trying to achieve this in the following way:

```
  private String checkFolder() throws URISyntaxException {
        String path=new File(MigrationsApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
                .toURI()).getPath()+"\\MigrationFiles";
        System.out.println("PATH2:"+path);
        File file=new File(path);
        if(!file.exists()){
            boolean folderCreated = file.mkdir();
            if(folderCreated){
                System.out.println("The folder MigrationFiles was created");
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

If I run the project from Intellij , the path that is returned is `C:\Users\fabio\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Migrations\target\classes\` and If I run it from the command line the return is `\Users\fabio\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Migrations\out\artifacts\Migrations_jar\Migrations.jar`
. Is this supposed to happen? Also how can I return the jar path only to `\artifacts\Migrations_jar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, the `.jar` file is the bundled `classes` directory.

You can test if the value returned is a directory or not, and strip the file name if it is.

```
Path p = Path.of(path);
if(! p.isDirectory()) {
    p = p.getParent();
}
return p.toString();
```

Comment: Should I strip the name if it is a directory or if it isn't?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. With the example you gave, if I am using the IDE, I will get the normal path to class, but it I am using the command line I will get the folder previous to the jar location?

Comment: I am getting an error because Path is a non static method

Comment: I didn't test the code.  Good news is that it comes with a 100% money back guarantee.  You can find the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: If the path isn't a directory, then presumably it's a jar file.  Your current approach either finds the classes directory, or a jar file.  This should get you a directory either way.